# Jenkins cant use parameters with remote ssh?

Tags: jenkins, ssh

Jenkins 2.264
SSH Plugin: 2.6.1

I am using SSH plugin for remote commands and I am trying to pass string/choice parameter defined in the job but my ssh command is not able to access the variable.

example:

```
echo $db
echo "$db"
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2.5 version of the [Jenkins SSH pluigin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh/) does mention:

> [[JENKINS-12191]](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12191) Support build variables (substitution variables) during command execution (env variables are exported before the script)

So if you do have a [parameterized build](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-with-parameters/):

[image: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/attachment/21348/Build%20Parameter.png]

The echo should work:

[image: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/attachment/21349/Execute%20SSH%20Build%20Step.png]

Comment: Apparently its is only not working when I enable "Execute each line".

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to run commands remotely using ssh, you can check this plugin which is quite easy to use with many feature flags https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-steps/

Comment: will have a look.